# How does a button at client sides knows which event to call on server side?

Tags: asp.net, .net, server-side

I went to an interview and i was asked this on ASP.Net :

There is a button on client side and on click it calls the button click event on server side.

How does it interact with the event on server side while the button is residing in the client side , what exactly is the mechanism behind it?

I responded that the button click event is called as we write the event name on onclick, but the interviewer said how does it interacts with the server?

I was not sure of the mechanism, can anybody explain?

Answer (score 0):

In a nutshell, click event is raised and captured on client side first. Then the event message is transmitted to the server through HTTP Post.

The page must interpret the post to determine what event occurred and then call the appropriate method in your code on the server to handle the event.

You can read more here - [ASP.NET Web Forms Server Control Event Model](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y3bwdsh3%28v=vs.140%29.aspx).

If you want to go a little bit deeper, you can read [Page Controller pattern  implemented in ASP.NET](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649415.aspx).

Answer (score -1):

From MSDN:

"If the request is a postback, control event handlers are called. After that, the Validate method of all validator controls is called, which sets the IsValid property of individual validator controls and of the page. (There is an exception to this sequence: the handler for the event that caused validation is called after validation.)"

So what this is saying is:

1. You click on an asp.net button with a server side event defined
2. The click causes a post back (you can look at the javascript generated for this)
3. The corresponding event is then called during the page life cycle (after page_load etc.)

See this article for the complete page life cycle:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: `2. The click causes a post back (you can look at the javascript generated for this)` The statement is not correct. You do not need JavaScript to post back to server.

Comment: you are correct - but most of the time the following is generated: function __doPostBack{...}